# My boolean is outputing none?

Tags: python

```
sunny = (input('Is it sunny outside?  '))

def isItSunny(sunny):

if sunny == True:
    return 'Its sunny outside, you may need sunsreen'

elif sunny == False:
    return 'Its cloudy, rain might be forcasted!'

print (str(isItSunny(sunny)))
```

When I run this short program and enter "True" or "False" I get an output of "none" instead of  return value any ideas? What might I be doing wrong? New to programming so still learning the quote on quote ropes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The string `'True'` is not equal to the literal `True`

```
>>> 'True' == True
False
```

You should be doing string comparisons

```
if sunny == 'True':
```